# Jenkins job builder docker build and publish plugin issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder, jenkins-docker

I am facing issue when Iam trying to build a Jenkins job using Jenkins job builder for docker build and publish plugin .  I have 2 issues here :

1.) in repository tag it is not accepting "/" . 
2.) registry url and password is not getting reflected in my jenkins job config (spacing is correct)
Here is my job template :

- job-template:
  name: '{name}_job'
  description: 'Automatically generated test'
  node: PROD-SLAVE
  builders:

  - shell: |
            BLAH BLAh
  - docker-build-publish:
          repo-name: "npu-cluster/{name}"
          repo-tag: 'BUILD_NUMBER'
          no-cache: false
          no-force-pull: false
          skip-build: false
          fingerprints: true
          skip-decorate: false
          skip-latest: true
          skip-tag: false
          file-path: '{name}/Dockerfile'
          **registry-url: url
          registry-credentials-id: credentials-id**
  - ssh-builder:
         ssh-user-ip: centos@ip
         command: blah blah

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while searching solutions for the same kind of issue. Maybe you have found the answer already, but here's what worked for me anyway:

```
- docker-build-publish:
    repo-name: 'sandboxname/component'
    registry:
       url: "https://yourremotelocation:port/"
       credentials-id: "yourcredentialsid"
```